# Pre-generated XML serializer assembly

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, web, xamarin.ios

I have a Visual Studio program that connects to a web service and a VMware environment. Part of the process is to get connected and understand the XML that comes back (i.e. translate it in to custom objects) which involves compiling a proxy file (XML serializer assembly dll file).

I have tried to use this file in my Monotouch program, but for some reason, Monotouch doesn't seemingly want to know about the XML serializer assembly. It ignores it and so I receive XML nodes back, rather than the XML being mapped back to the correct custom object via the XML serializer assembly.

How can I get Monotouch to recognize the file and use it?

Comment: I have added the abc.XmlSerializer.dll file to the project and referenced it within the class, as below.

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerAssemblyAttribute(AssemblyName="VimService.XmlSerializers")]

I dont get any errors but it is ignored.

If I dont use the pregenerated file and use the class file with uncommented XmlAttributes in it then it works fine, it just takes way too long to instantiate the class.

Comment: For reference:  http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.dsg.doc%2Fsdk_c_sharp_development.5.4.html

That details how to generate the precompiled serializer assembly. I cant post the class here with the commented out xmlattributes and the serializer dll if required. They are quite large though.

Comment: sorry - meant to say I can post here in the above comment...

Comment: are you building the Serializer dll in MonoTouch (MonoDevelop) or in Visual Studio?

Comment: I had built it in Windows using sgen.exe - not sure how to build it in MonoDevelop? I did try using the silverlight utility (although this is a dotnet2 web service) but the resulting file was 80MB in size!!!?!!

Comment: Update: I have built the two service dll and the serializer dll under my mac using wsdl, mcs and sgen. Remarked out the XML lines and rebuilt the service dll. Added both in to the project as references. Still doesnt work - the serializer isnt being used when you call any commands from the class contained in the service dll.

Comment: This serializer dll might not even be used in MonoTouch at all--it is a different implementation underneath.  Have you considered performance testing against parsing the XML by hand?  XmlReader/Writer might get alot better performance when you take out the reflection it has to do.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the comment! Would you be able to provide a small example piece of code on what this might look like?

Comment: It would be reading/writing the XML by hand, this MSDN article explains a bit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w1e57w(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Mono or any Mono-powered products (like MonoTouch or MonoDroid) support XmlSerializerAssembly.